# Is "looking into potentially.... " a redundant statement?

Tags: phrases, redundancy

Is "looking into potentially.... " a redundant statement?

Ex: We are looking into potentially moving our development from one source to another.

Answer (score 1):

Whether "potentially" and "looking into" are redundant depends on the facts of the situation. If we change Zabari's example to "I'm potentially looking into buying a house, I think it'll be a great investment", that would be redundant.

"My company is potentially changing health insurance suppliers; I've been assigned to look into it" isn't redundant because the entity that created the potential is distinct from the entity that is looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

"Looking into" means investigating the ramifications.  "Potentially" means possibly could happen, possibly not.

The investigation would be expected to weigh the relative benefits of the two alternatives, and hence it is in no way redundant.

Comment: I am potentially going to die from eating to much pizza.  I'm not looking into it because, to hell with it, I like pizza.  Yeah, not redundant.  Though when used together not always elegant.